# fs.readFileSync is not a function error in pdftopic plugin

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress

I m trying to convert PDF file to PNG using pdftopic
Code used:

```
 const { pdftobuffer } = require('pdftopic');
 const fs = require('fs')
      
      const pdf = fs.readFileSync('cypress/template/IPID JL HOME.pdf', null);
      
      pdftobuffer(pdf, 0).then((buffer) => {
          fs.writeFileSync('cypress/template/IPID JL HOME.png', buffer, null);
      })
   }
```

Getting below error in console:
fs.readFileSync is not a function